# Tableau Desktop - Create an Index from a Specific Average Timeframe

Tags: tableau-desktop

I want to calculate an Average of SUM([SHIPMENTS]) between 1/3/2021 and 1/24/2021 ([CALENDAR_DT]), and then use that average (based on which shippers are selected) as the Index for my dataset. [CALENDAR_DT] is at the weekly level, so the dates selected above would cover 1/3/2021 thru 1/30/2021

[Index Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XB5Qy.png)

I've been able to create a standard Index based on a single week's-worth of data (1/3/2021). However I'm having trouble creating an index of the average of the first month of 2021. In this case there are 4 weeks I want to average: Week 1 - [Calendar_DT] = 1/3/2021, Week 2 - [Calendar_DT] = 1/10/2021, Week 3 - [Calendar_DT] = 1/17/2021, Week 4 - [Calendar_DT] = 1/24/2021. The date represented in [Calendar_DT] is the first day of each week. I have provided a link to my TWBX packaged workbook on the Tableau boards below. Appreciate any help!

https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D78b00000AxodCCAR/detail?fromEmail=1&s1oid=00D4T000000Dj8G&s1nid=0DB4T000000GnPK&s1uid=0058b00000I2JGO&s1ext=0&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&emtm=1701280476111&emvtk=tVMGeN01WoRCOe8wuf_rvaLbAP9xi81GDd1Z7ho83L8%3D

Comment: Tableau's Level of Detail (LOD) calculations are typically a key element in addressing this type of problem. I recommend first learning about LOD calcs and experimenting with them on some simple data. There are 3 variant types, but FIXED LOD calcs are the ones to start with (most flexible, simplest to understand, and usually the right answer. You'll also want to be sure to understand how filters interact with LOD calcs, and how LOD calcs fall into the order of operations. Depending on what you're doing, you may need also to use Context Filters or nested LOD calcs.

Comment: P.S. Many of the problems that call for an LOD calc could also be addressed with table calcs - that's your other main option. But in most cases, try LOD calcs first. Both types of calcs take a little time to learn to use well, but the time investment opens up alot of capability.